# Network Utilization Percentage - windows

Tags: windows, command-prompt

Is there command to get the network utilization percentage in windows using command-prompt?

Thanks

Comment: Probably.  Not programming related, tho.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the answers to a prior Stack Overflow question [How do i monitor network traffic on Windows from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171336/how-do-i-monitor-network-traffic-on-windows-from-the-command-line) may be of some help to you.

Comment: That one is for monitoring and uses a third party tool tshark.

Answer (score 1):

Found the following site that might help: http://poshcode.org/1900

Comment: The link is down. You should always copy the relevant parts into your answer.